# How to give the GoogleMap API inside a fragment a specific map seach

Tags: android

So, I basically put a GoogleMaps API inside a fragment in my app, and I want to give it a specific default search like we do with Intent, but in this case im using fragment instead of an intent.`public class LocalGymsFragment extends Fragment {

```
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_local_gyms, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;


                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try implementing the GoogleMaps API on a constraint layout or new GoogleMaps Activity. This is because Fragments aren't just a cup of tea. It is tough implementing this on fragments.